# Get and print meta content from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How do I get and print the meta content?

Like the profile picture(avator circle)title, username(subTitle), description(des), followers(val), following(val), instagram(profile-link_media), website(profile-link_href) and list of video urls if available.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://likee.video/@HouseofB"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://likee.video/@HouseofB"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

des = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'description'})
print(des)
```

But I can't quite get it to work getting the information as sorted above mentioned.

I want to print it like this:

Profile picture: url

User: HouseofBrooklyn

Userid: @HouseofB

Followers: 8.6M

Likes: 64.0M

Instagram: url

Website: url

Videos:

list of urls

In advance, thank you for your kind help at teaching me!

Comment: What exactly do you mean "can't quite get it to work"?  Are you getting errors?  Are you getting unexpected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired data from API.As data is loaded dynamically by JS via API which is `POST` method.

**Example:**

```
import requests

payload = {"likeeId":"HouseofB"}

headers= {
    'content-type': 'application/json'}
api_url='https://api.like-video.com/likee-activity-flow-micro/official_website/WebView/getProfileDetail'

req=requests.post(api_url,headers=headers,json=payload).json()
print(req)

out=[]

out.append({
    'User Name':req['data']['userinfo']['user_name'],
    'Followers': req['data']['userinfo']['fansCount'],
    'Link':req['data']['userinfo']['link'],
    'Likes':req['data']['userinfo']['allLikeCount'],
    'img_link':req['data']['userinfo']['data1']
    })

print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

building on @F.Hoque 's answer.
This code makes an extra `POST` request for videos

```
import requests

likeeID = "HouseofB"

detail_api = "https://api.like-video.com/likee-activity-flow-micro/official_website/WebView/getProfileDetail"
videos_api = "https://api.like-video.com/likee-activity-flow-micro/videoApi/getUserVideo"


# Details Fetch
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = {'likeeId': likeeID}
details = requests.post(detail_api, headers=headers, json=payload).json()['data']['userinfo']


# Videos Fetch
payload = {"uid": details['uid'], "lastPostId": "", "tabType": 0, "count": 99}
videos_res = requests.post(videos_api, headers=headers, json=payload).json()
videos = [i['videoUrl'] for i in videos_res['data']['videoList']]


# Merge
details = {
    "Profile Picture":  details['data1'], # Profile Picture URL
    "User":  details['nick_name'], # Name
    "UserID":  f"@{details['user_name']}", # username/likeeID
    "Followers":  details['fansCount'], # exact count
    "Likes":  details['allLikeCount'], # exact count
    "Website": details['link'], # website
    "Videos": videos
}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(details)
```

Answer (score 0):

A metta tag will typically look like

```
<meta name="description" content="description info"/>
```

You should try to grab the content attribute.

```
des = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'description'})
print(des['content'])
```